# Minimum memory requirements for a computational graph

Tags: graph-theory

A computation is represented by a bipartite directed acyclic graph that has operation nodes and value nodes.
An operation node can receive and output any amount of value nodes, but a value node can only be "created" by 1 operation (but used as input to many).
A program "runs" the graph by performing the operation nodes in some topological order. Once all operations that use a given value have been calculated, the value can be removed from memory.
What is the minimum memory requirement that the program needs?

In principle we can go over all possible orders of operations and calculate the maximum memory needed for each one, then take the minimum of all maximums. This take too much time though.
Any better algorithms to get the minimal value?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This seems similar to computing the width of a poset.  It is certainly a graph partitioning problem, in that we can divide the graph into the "already-computed" and "yet-to-be-computed" regions.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) states that graph partitioning problems are usually NP-hard.